# Prompt user to add IP ranges using batch file

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, batch, ip

I have tried

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" address=192.168.230.254 mask=255.255.255.0 gate=192.168.230.1
netsh interface ip   set dnsservers "Ethernet 3"  static 8.8.8.8 validate=no
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver  "Ethernet 3" address=8.8.4.4 index=2 validate=no

pause
```

to set the laptop's IP automatically, but I couldn't add more IP ranges. Is there any way I could add specific IP ranges using the batch file with a user prompt? Any suggestions or websites for references?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format the code properly.

Comment: I can’t tell whether you’re asking about configuring your network or writing a batch file. Please pick one, and be clearer. You say “Is there any way I could add specific IP ranges using the batch file with a user prompt?” What do you mean by “specific”? Either you (the programmer) know the values now, or you (the user) will specify them at run-time; it can’t be both. In the first draft of this question, you said that something you tried didn’t work. People can probably help you more if you say how it failed. And, if you’re talking about Ethernet, why did you use the [wireless-networking] tag?

Comment: Writing a batch file that can configure my laptop's IP to the required IP addresses. when I double click the batch file it would prompt me (the user) to key in the specific (desired IP) ranges, then the computer's IP would be set accordingly. [example I want to set "192.168.0.10 - 192.168.230.10" ]. When I double click the batch file, it would prompt me to key in the IP ranges I want, so I will type "192.168.0.10 - 192.168.230.10"  and it will run automatically and my laptop will have the IP ranges from "192.168.0.10 to 192.168.230.10"